# How to combine a table and multiple plots into one combined plot in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to combine multiple plots and a table into one combined plot in R. My plot was great until I tried to include the table as well. This is when I received this message: Error in gList(...) : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList". I am guessing that it is not working best all the plots were made via ggplots2 and resulted in lists and the table was just a fancied up dataframe using kable function. Below is my code for the creation of the table as well as the code for the combining of plots

Table Code:

```
table1 <- FinalPitches %>%
  arrange(desc(Pitches)) %>%
  kable(col.names = c("Player Name", "Pitch Type", "Pitches", "Velocity", "Horizontal Break", "Vertical Break",
                      "Spin Rate", "VAA", "Strike%","CSW%", "Whiff%", "Stuff+")) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Combining code:

```
# Define the first arrangeGrob
first_arrange <- arrangeGrob(
  BreakChart,
  LocationMap,
  nrow = 1,
  widths = c(0.40, 0.50)  # Adjusted widths to add up to 1
)

# Define the second arrangeGrob with smaller widths
second_arrange <- arrangeGrob(
  Even1,
  Ahead1,
  Behind1,
  TwoStrikes1,
  nrow = 1,
  widths = c(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)  # Adjusted widths to make them smaller
)

# Define the third
third_arrange <- arrangeGrob(
  table1,
  nrow = 1,
  widths = c(0.15)  # Adjusted widths to make them smaller
)

# Combine the plots into a grid layout
combined_plot6 <- grid.arrange(
  first_arrange,   # First row (top)
  second_arrange, # Second row (bottom)
  third_arrange,  # third row (bottom)
  ncol = 1,        # Single column layout
  nrow = 3,        # Dividing the grid into two rows
  heights = unit(c(1, 1, 0.5), c("null", "null", "null"))  # Adjusted heights for the rows
)

# Display the combined plot
print(combined_plot6)
```

I apologize for no reproducible code, but if anyone can get it to somewhat work with the table and plots being included together that would be terrific and I will accept as right answer. Thanks!! Here is a photo of what I'd like it to look like. The visualizations at the bottom are perfect, I just cant get the table added in to the graphic.

[image]

Comment: Please include a sketch of the expected output in the absence of a reproducible question.

Comment: Thank you for your question. If you could include a sample of your data, enough that we are able to reproduce your problem (use `dput()`) that would be great!

Comment: `tableGrob` from {gridExtra} creates grobs from tables, with some formatting options: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html

Comment: @Peter I believe I added a picture to the original post. Let me know if you can't see it. Really any example provided with a ggplot graphic or two and a "fancied up" table that is made from a dataframe would help!!

Comment: @MarkHill 
Diamonds <- diamonds[(1:6),]

table1 <- Diamonds %>%
  arrange(desc(carat)) %>%
  kable(col.names = c("carat", "cut", "color", "clarity", "depth", "table", "price",
                      "z", "y", "z")) %>%
  kable_styling() 

print(table1)
Here is reproducible code for table. Honestly any code successfully showing any ggplot graphic and this table would be great. I can fiddle around with it to make table fit and insert my graphics in. I just want the combined plot to combine ggplot plots and this table. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the picture, which is helpful, see answer which obviously will need to be adapted for your own case, design and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach which could be applied to your question:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gridExtra) # for tableGrob
library(dplyr)# to help with creating a minimal table
library(tibble) # to remove rownames

#preparing illustrative table and graphs

tbl <- 
  mtcars |> 
  mutate(names = row.names(mtcars)) |> 
  select(names, everything()) |> 
  remove_rownames()

# I'm not sure kable is easily convertable into a grob,
# so use gridExtra for table, as this play better with grobs and patchwork.

tbl1 <- tableGrob(tbl[1:3, 1:10], theme=ttheme_minimal(), rows=NULL)


p1 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point()


p2 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point()

#nominal pie chart

pie1 <- mtcars  |> 
  summarise(count = n(), .by = cyl)  |> 
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = "x", y = count, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = count), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 8) +  
    labs(title = "Pie chart 1") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")

plot_layout <- 
  "AAAA
   BBCC
   DEFG"  
  
  wrap_plots(tbl1, p1, p2, pie1, pie1, pie1, pie1,
             design = plot_layout)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, I will try later. Marking as correct answer as I should be able to get it to work on my end. Thanks again